# How to select following sibling tag with xpath

Tags: xpath, python-2.7, lxml

I have a HTML file like this:

```
<div id="note">
 <a name="overview"></a>
 <h3>Overview</h3>
 <p>some text1...</p>
 <a name="description"></a>
 <h3>Description</h3>
 <p>some text2 ...</p>
</div>
                              `
```

I would like to retrieve the paragraph, for each header.
for example, overview: some text1
description: some text 2 
...
I want to write this in python using xpath.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all `h3` tags, iterate over them, and on each step of iteration loop, find the next sibling tag `p`:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

URL = "http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/628463"
response = urllib2.urlopen(URL)

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, parser)

for header in tree.iter('h3'):
    paragraph = header.xpath('(.//following-sibling::p)[1]')
    if paragraph:
        print "%s: %s" % (header.text, paragraph[0].text)
```

prints:

```
Overview: The Ruby on Rails 3.0 and 2.3 JSON parser contain a vulnerability that may result in arbitrary code execution.
Description: Thanks to Lawrence Pit of Mirror42 for discovering the vulnerability.
Impact: Thanks to Lawrence Pit of Mirror42 for discovering the vulnerability.
Solution: Thanks to Lawrence Pit of Mirror42 for discovering the vulnerability.
Vendor Information : Thanks to Lawrence Pit of Mirror42 for discovering the vulnerability.
CVSS Metrics : Thanks to Lawrence Pit of Mirror42 for discovering the vulnerability.
References: Thanks to Lawrence Pit of Mirror42 for discovering the vulnerability.
Credit: Thanks to Lawrence Pit of Mirror42 for discovering the vulnerability.
Feedback: If you have feedback, comments, or additional information about this vulnerability, please send us 
Subscribe to Updates: Receive security alerts, tips, and other updates.
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I've got this error :
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 1 and head, line 1, column 485
for this code : 
from StringIO import StringIO
from lxml import etree
import urllib
url = 'http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/628463'
text = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
f = StringIO(text)
tree = etree.parse(f)

headers = tree.xpath('//h3')
for header in headers:
    paragraph = header.xpath('(.//following-sibling::p)[1]')[0]
    print "%s: %s" % (header.text, paragraph.text)

p.s. I'm new with python and xpath.